# Cornering button to bottom left android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to do a menu exactly like CandyCrush's: Two buttons (play and connect) in the center and then right at the bottom left, there's another button (the CC's arrow). I manage to position the first to buttons, but I am unable to position the last one at the bottom left of my activity. How can I position it? This is my xml and I use Relative Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/balao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
    android:background="@null"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"  
    android:maxHeight="180dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/balao" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"  
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"   
    android:layout_below="@+id/balao"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/tutor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play"  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxWidth="50dp"  
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"   
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/tutor" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/corner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/corner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post screenshot plz?

Comment: Alright, problem solved, it was indeed the wrapcontent/fillparent thing. Btw, how can I qualify both answers as the best?

Comment: you can upvote all answers and select answer which you find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For last button, use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

i.e.:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/corner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/corner"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

weight properties is not applicable in RelativeLayout so remove from xml :

```
android:layout_weight="1" // remove this properties
```

Set bottom button to lef side simple set width as wrap instead fill :

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```